# PHP -> JS via AJAX - data types

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I need to get an `array` from `PHP` to `JS` using `AJAX`.

I use a standard ajax call and the data is returned as an object.

I can easily loop through this using `Jquery`.

After reading many posts online, the common practice is to send back `JSON`.

My question is, why use `JSON`. If I was to use it, I would need to convert the array to `JSON` PHP side (server side ) and then parse it in the JS (client side) to be able to loop through it.

Why use `JSON` if it requires these extra steps, why not just parse back an object from `PHP`.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help. *Text* is what is moved back and forth with AJAX.

Comment: It sounds like you are using JSON, without knowing it.  Ajax can only return strings; not objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I use a standard ajax call and the data is returned as an object.

No, it isn't. The data is sent in some (probably) text format (such as JSON).

Some code then converts it into an object. jQuery (for instance) will do that automatically if the server sends back a `Content-Type: application/json` header or if you specify `dataType: "json"` in the options.

> My question is, why use JSON.

It is:

- based on JavaScript's native data model (which includes the things programmers most care about: ordered arrays, collections of named things, numbers, booleans and strings)
- simple
- well supported with libraries in many languages

> Why use JSON if it requires these extra steps, why not just parse back an object from PHP.

You can't pass an "object" back from PHP because an object is just a program's understanding about how a bunch of pieces of data in the computer's RAM relate to each other.

Sending it to another computer would be akin to sending the thoughts in your head to another brain.

You have to translate them into a shared, transmittable language first.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is - you right - the way.

JSON is easy & quick to parse with JavaScript.
JSON : JavaScript Object Notation.

Easier & faster to parse than xml, the old past way.

Json or XML, cause Php object cannot be passed to JS...
But you easily can convert : json_encode(phparray)

That s it : json is that way common to php and JS...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple:

**PHP** is a **server-side language** which is interpret by PHP's zend engine  where as **javascript** is a **client-side language** which is interpret by **javascript engine**.

So **javascript engine** can't understand **PHP objects** that's why we are converting **PHP object** into a JSON objects which are understand by **PHP's zend engine** as well as **javascript engine**.